# Time Javascript not compitible in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datetime, firefox

I have problem with my website lately... i cant find the solution how to fix...

Lately my website using chrome to run.. but after flash issue most of my web not responding... and i after switch to firefox.. but my time and month not working properly... it come out undefined and NaN NaN... upper code is TIME and below is Month...i manage to solve month by doing doing short month... but time.. idk what wrong

### time

```
 objData.forEach(function (entry) {
                        var dateSplitStartTime = entry.StartTime.split(" ");
                        var dateSplitEndTime = entry.EndTime.split(" ");
                        var currDateTimeStart = new Date(dateSplitStartTime[1] + ' ' + dateSplitStartTime[0] + ', ' + dateSplitStartTime[2] + ' ' + dateSplitStartTime[3]);
                        var currDateTimeEnd = new Date(dateSplitEndTime[1] + ' ' + dateSplitEndTime[0] + ', ' + dateSplitEndTime[2] + ' ' + dateSplitEndTime[3]);

                        var strDisplyTime;

                        if (currDateTimeStart.getDate() == currDateTimeEnd.getDate() && currDateTimeStart.getMonth() == currDateTimeEnd.getMonth()
                            && currDateTimeStart.getFullYear() == currDateTimeEnd.getFullYear()) {
                            if (entry.IsAllDay == true) {
                                strDisplyTime = "All Day";
                            } else {
                                if (entry.Type == 'SCHEDULER') {
                                    strDisplyTime = currDateTimeStart.getTimeFormat();
                                } else {
                                    strDisplyTime = currDateTimeStart.getTimeFormat() + ' - ' + currDateTimeEnd.getTimeFormat()
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            strDisplyTime = currDateTimeStart.getShortDate() + ' ' + currDateTimeStart.getTimeFormat() + ' - ' +
                                currDateTimeEnd.getShortDate() + ' ' + currDateTimeEnd.getTimeFormat();
                        }
```

Month is below

```
function convertStringToDate(dateStr) {
var a = dateStr.split(" ");
var d = a[0].split("-");
var t = a[1].split(":");
var date = new Date(d[0], (d[1] - 1), d[2], t[0], t[1], t[2]);
return date;
}

Date.locale = {
en: {
    month_names_short: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    month_names: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    day_names: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    extensions: ["th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "tn", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "tn", "th", "th", "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "tn", "th", "th",
        "th", "st"]
}
};

//Date.prototype.getShortDate = function (lang) {
//    lang = lang && (lang in Date.locale) ? lang : 'en';
//    return this.getDate() + ' ' +           Date.locale[lang].month_names[this.getMonth()].substr(0, 3) + ' ' +
//        this.getFullYear();
//}; - not compitable with firefox - added short month_names_short

Date.prototype.getShortDate = function (lang) {
lang = lang && (lang in Date.locale) ? lang : 'en';
return this.getDate() + ' ' + Date.locale[lang].month_names_short[this.getMonth()] + ' ' +
    this.getFullYear();
};

Date.prototype.getTimeFormat = function (lang) {
lang = lang && (lang in Date.locale) ? lang : 'en';
return (this.getHours() === 0) ? 12 : ((this.getHours() > 12) ? this.getHours() - 12 : this.getHours()) + ':' + ((this.getMinutes() > 9) ? this.getMinutes() : '0' + this.getMinutes()) + ' ' + ((this.getHours() > 11) ? 'pm' : 'am');
```

};

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()` works in FF and CH... i don't think you don't need all the complication.

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming with Java? Why the [tag:java] tag?

Comment: Or `asp.net` for that matter.

Comment: what is this, alot of complaining then answering.. what happend to stackflow lol

Comment: in which line the problem is?`it come out undefined and NaN NaN` which is 'it'?

Comment: strDisplyTime  @shreesha

Comment: we do not have `getTimeFormat` function with `date`.check the link http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Comment: i added my getTimeFormat, cuz there diffrent language in my browser , so i need to do special code for it. @shreesha

Comment: dont think mine work, i also wonder why .. @dandavis

Comment: You ... should write... your... question nicely .. and stop using ... so many ...

Comment: im sorry that my english not very good... @JK.

Comment: i have fix my self.. solution for this is

Answer (score 0):

My answer is , in sql i date varchar as (120)

and convert them to

```
   var dateSplitStartTime = entry.StartTime.split(" ");
                        var dateSplitEndTime = entry.EndTime.split(" ");

                        var d = dateSplitStartTime[0].split("-");
                        var d1 = dateSplitEndTime[0].split("-");

                        var t = dateSplitStartTime[1].split(":");
                        var t1 = dateSplitEndTime[1].split(":");

                        var currDateTimeStart = new Date(d[0], (d[1] - 1), d[2], t[0], t[1], t[2]);
                        var currDateTimeEnd = new Date(d1[0], (d1[1] - 1), d1[2], t1[0], t1[1], t1[2]);
```

and it work both browser now... thanks for some of u helping